# Does Javascript run lines of code in order? and finish processing then move on?

Tags: javascript, alasql

I am trying to write some code in Javascript for first time, and I am guessing I dont get something conceptually!

The following code for me works fine :

```
var db = new alasql.Database("db");
db.exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Myonetwo;');

var aaa = db.exec('select * into Myonetwo from json("http://localhost:8080/app1")',[],function(res){
    db.exec('select * from Myonetwo;',[],function(bbb){

            console.log(bbb.length);    
        });
});
```

But this one which is the same but not function inside function embedded, Does not work.

```
var db = new alasql.Database("db");
db.exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Myonetwo;');

var aaa = db.exec('select * into Myonetwo from json("http://localhost:8080/app1")');
var bbb = db.exec('select * from Myonetwo;');
console.log(bbb.length);
```

Also Is getting result as a function defined as one of arguments something usuall for all Javascripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the `exec` function is **asynchronous**, so in your 2nd example the `bbb` assignment line will happen prior to the `aaa` assignment line finishing.

This is why `exec` has a *callback function* as it's last parameter.

In your first code snippit the timeline of events will be something like:

- first exec call
- some time passes...
- first exec callback happens
- second exec call executes
- second exec callback happens

In this case you **know** that the second exec call will happen after the first exec call.

Your second code snippit's timeline will be:

- first exec call
- second exec call
- either first or second exec call finishes (non deterministic)
- either first or second exec call finishes (non deterministic)

You can see that this will have a bearing on your logic.

Here is a good article to learn more about asynchrounous programming: https://blog.risingstack.com/asynchronous-javascript/

Comment: Is that correct? It seems that the (ordinal) first example is asynchronous, while the (ordinal) second example is synchronous. The [docs](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Alasql-Object) suggest that when the function `exec` contains three parameters there will be an async call.

Comment: Thanks @franklin for pointing there. First of all, I did not know anything about asynchronous. But reading the link you gave me, I was like, well this should be sync. Then I found this [link](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Async) and it seems because of that json() part I am getting async

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink, Thanks for your answer. Is there a way I put a wait or something there, so I can somehow get back to sync model?

Comment: @RoozbehG I'm not sure how far this could help in this situation, but you may want to look at JavaScript "promises".

Answer (score 3):

Yes Javascript does run lines of code in order. But is also contains **asynchronous/deferred** programming elements.

The concept can be looked up here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

It boils down to this:

```
console.log("a");
console.log("b");    // output will be a, b, c
console.log("c");

// output will be a, b, c
```

then again

```
console.log("a");
setTimeout(function(){
   concole.log("b");
},0);
console.log("c");

//output will be a, c, b
```

The reason is that the code to print "b" appears both times before `console.log("c")` but it is indeed not both times executed before. In the second case it is queued in the EventLoop via the `window.setTimeout(function, timeout)` function

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said it's because javascript, or in this case, NodeJS is asynchronous in nature. The reason is because it's very efficient to **delegate** I/O tasks because they take much longer to execute than ordinary tasks.

I think it can be explained well with an analogy:

JavaScript is like a builder. Lets call him (or her) *Bob*.

#### Scenario 1 - equivilant to second example in question

> Customer asks *Bob* to build a house.
>
> *Bob* is too busy to do the work alone so he asks *Joe*, a
>   brick layer to help.
>
> *Joe* starts laying bricks.
>
> In the meantime, *Bob* asks *Paul* the plumber to put pipes in the walls.
>
> *Pauls* beings to lay pipes ... *hang on* .. there are no
>   walls yet
>
> [*malfunction*]

In JavaScript the code might look like this:

```
Joe.layBricks()
Paul.layPipes()
```

and that is basically what happens in your second example

#### Scenario 2 - equivalent to your first example

Bob tries again:

> *Customer* asks *Bob* to build a house.
>
> *Bob* asks Joe to lay some bricks.
>
> But this time he tells *Joe* that when he is finished *he must tell
>   Paul* (known as a callback) he is ready.
>
> Paul already knows what he needs to do but just needs to know when he
>   can do it.
>
> Much better. The work will get done.
>
> Now *Bob* can even ask painter *Pat* to paint the house when the plumbing
>   is done in the same way.

The code looks like this:

```
Joe.layBricks(Paul.layPipes(Pat.paintWalls()))
```

Look familiar? (should be close to example 1)

#### How its done in other languages

An easy thing for *Bob* to do would be to carry out all the work himself but that would not be very efficient or scalable. That's how a lot of languages work. But *NodeJS* has a better way which is where callbacks come into play.

Other advanced languages allow you to define your own threads. But they are pretty complex and can be difficult to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the code:

```
var db = new alasql.Database("db");
var res = db.exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Myonetwo;\
     select * into Myonetwo from json("http://localhost:8080/app1");\
     select * from Myonetwo;');
console.log(res);
```

In this case AlaSQL will run all operators sequentially (even they are async) and save them into res variable.

In other case you need to rewrite the code with callback:

```
var db = new alasql.Database("db");
var res = db.exec('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Myonetwo;');
var res = db.exec('select * into Myonetwo from \
     json("http://localhost:8080/app1")',[],function(){
        var bbb = db.exec('select * from Myonetwo;');
        console.log(res);
});
```

In your example you need to use callback only for the second line, because JSON() function in AlaSQL is async.